# Exchange 2010: Get all-time LastLogonDate

Tags: powershell, statistics, exchange-server-2010

When using PowerShell's

```
Get-LogonStatistics
```

it seems to show only details for the last week.

But I'm interesseted in accounts beeing inactive since a longer time.

Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a mailbox server in the command, it should list the status of all the mailboxes in all the databases on that server:

```
Get-LogonStatistics -Server mbxservername
```

Comment: According to Microsoft's documentation it should work. In that case try `Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics`